# How to store objects in plist

Tags: objective-c, encryption, nsdictionary, plist, nsvalue

I have some `CGPoint`s that I need to store in a `NSDictionary` then write to a file. Later, I need to be able to load the file into a `NSDictionary` and access the `CGPoint` within.

`self.dict` is the NSDictionary I want to store points in.

```
- (void)setPoint:(CGPoint)point forKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSValue *value = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:point];
    [self.dict setValue:value forKey:key];
}
```

I also want the information to be encrypted. So I convert the `NSDictionary` to `NSData` to encrypt it.

```
- (void)encryptDictionaryWithKey:(NSData *)key writeToFile:(NSString *)file {
    NSData *encryptedDict = [[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:self] encryptWithKey:key];
    [encryptedDict writeToFile:file atomically:YES];
}
```

Then to get the information from the file, decrypt it, and put it in `NSDictionary` form:

```
+ (NSDictionary *)dictionaryWithContentsOfEncryptedData:(NSData *)data     decryptWithKey:(NSData *)key {
    NSData *decryptedData = [data decryptedWithKey:key];
    return (NSDictionary *)[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:decryptedData];
}
```

I can put some other values (like `NSNumber`) into the `NSDictionary`, encrypt it and write it to file, then get it from file and decrypt it... and the value is still in tact. So my code seems to be fine. But it won't work with `NSValue`.

I use this to get CGPoint from `NSValue`. At this point, `self.plist` may have been (but not necessarily) encrypted, written to file, then set to an unencrypted version of the file.

```
- (CGPoint)pointForKey:(NSString *)key {
    NSValue *value = [self.prefs objectForKey:key];
    return [value CGPointValue];
}
```

This code only returns 0,0 (and `value == nil`) if `self.plist` has been encrypted, written to file, then loaded from the file and unencrypted.

So the `NSValue` with `CGPoint` seems to be set to `nil` during the process of writing to the file. I have no idea what I did wrong, so any help is appreciated . Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the `CGPoint` into an object that can be stored in a plist. For example, the 
[`CGPointCreateDictionaryRepresentation()` function](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGGeometry/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGPointCreateDictionaryRepresentation) will convert a `CGPoint` into an `NSDictionary` (or rather, a `CFDictionaryRef` which can be cast to an `NSDictionary`). You can store that in the plist, and then convert it *back* to a `CGPoint` using the `CGPointMakeWithDictionaryRepresentation()` companion function when you are loading the plist.